# Bash if statement based on file number

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Had a quick question regarding an if statement in bash. Currently I have the following, which takes all the even numbered csv files and then prints all the lines three times.

```
sed -i 'p;p;p' *[02468].csv
```

However, is there a way I can print, say, 2 lines *if* the odd-numbered file (*right* after each even-numbered file) has less than 20 lines? In other words,

```
sed -i 'p;p' *[02468].csv IF (# lines of [13579].csv RIGHT after each [02468].csv < 20)
```

To clarify, say, 5.csv has 19 lines. Then I will print 4.csv's lines twice. But say 7.csv has 21 lines. Then I will print 6.csv's lines thrice.

Sample Input even-numbered csv file:

`STATE UNIVERSITY`

Desired output if odd-numbered csv file (even-numbered+1) < 20 lines:

```
STATE UNIVERSITY 
STATE UNIVERSITY
```

Desired output if odd-numbered csv file (even-numbered+1) > 20 lines:

```
STATE UNIVERSITY 
STATE UNIVERSITY
STATE UNIVERSITY
```

Comment: could you please post sample input file and sample expected output ?

Comment: Apologies -- I edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
threshold=20
prevLineCount=$threshold
while IFS= read -r fname; do
  [[ $fname =~ ([0-9])\.csv$ ]] # match the last digit before the .csv suffix
  if (( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} % 2 == 0 )); then # even
    sedScript='p;p;p'
    (( prevLineCount < threshold )) && sedScript='p;p'
    sed -n "$sedScript" "$fname"
  else # odd
    prevLineCount=$(wc -l < "$fname") # count lines
    # Don't print odd-numbered files
  fi
done < <(printf '%s\n' *[0-9].csv | sort -r)
```

<sup>Note that for safety I've omitted the `-i` to prevent in-place updating; add it, once you've confirmed that the script works as intended.

Also note that `-n` was added, as without it you'd print each line an *additional* time, given that the default is to print (possibly modified) input lines.</sup>

Assumptions:

- Reverse-sorting the filenames yields the desired processing order (highest index first).
- Filenames have no embedded newlines (such files would be very rare).
- If the *first* filename (the one with the *highest digit* before the suffix) is *even*, it is assumed that 3 lines should be printed; replace `prevLineCount=$threshold` with `prevLineCount=0` to default to printing 2 lines.